# Properly setting DeleteOnTermination on an existing EBS volume using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

Digging through the code (consider [this](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/8a35e954cd73b2ddec6c4d9fee4070b41d275da7), for instance), I found that I can read the attribute using:

```
instance.block_device_mapping['/dev/sdz'].delete_on_termination
```

...and toggle it using:

```
instance.modify_attribute('blockdevicemapping', ['/dev/sdz=1']) # toggle on
instance.modify_attribute('blockdevicemapping', ['/dev/sdz']) # toggle off
```

But it's a-symmetrical and I feel like I'm missing some higher level functionality.

Shouldn't it be more like:

```
block_device_type = instance.block_device_mapping['/dev/sdz']
block_device_type.delete_on_termination = True
block_device_type.save() # I made this API up
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You turn this setting on and off with a list of the formatted string `'%s=%d'`.

*Switch to on*

```
>>> inst.modify_attribute('blockDeviceMapping', ['/dev/sda1=1'])
```

*Switch to off*

```
>>> inst.modify_attribute('blockDeviceMapping', ['/dev/sda1=0'])
```

---

I verified changes outside of python after each attempt to change the setting using:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id i-7890abcd --attribute blockDeviceMapping
```

1. Calling `inst.modify_attribute('blockDeviceMapping', ['/dev/sda1'])` (the string lacks `=0`) did not produce any change.
2. Assigning to `inst.block_device_mapping['/dev/sda1'].delete_on_termination` also did not produce any change.

---

After calling `modify_attribute`, the value of `delete_on_termination` on local block device objects is unchanged.

---

I walk through the whole process at:
http://f06mote.com/post/77239804736/amazon-ec2-instance-safety-tweak-turn-off-delete-on

Comment: Didn't verify yet, but this looks very thorough; than you!